# JQuery horizontal centred div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to center all div's using a JQuery or CSS?

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/2zwu7/

```
<div id="parrent">
    <div class="item">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="item">
         content
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `float: left;` from `#parrent .item` selector and add `display: inline-block;`

[jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/2zwu7/1/)

Comment: `display: inline-block;` IE need Fix?

Comment: @Dmitriy for old versions of IE you will need to trigger `hasLayout` so just add `*display:inline;zoom:1;` to your `#parrent .item` selector